# ListView blank after populating

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, datatable

I have a `Dictionary<string, string>` obejct, whose data should be filtered in real time through the text submitted in a `TextBox` control and then shown in a `ListView` control.

The solution I came up with was:

- converting the `Dictionary<string, string>` to `DataTable`
- using the textbox's `TextChanged` event to trigger the filter
- putting the filtered records to a `DataRow[]` array, passing said array as an argument to a custom method to populate the `ListView` object

Now, this is how I convert the dictionary:

```
static DataTable dtDepartments { get; set; }
static Dictionary<string, string> GetDepartments(string _depNum, out bool _isOff) 
 {
     // retrieve the list from a SQL Server DB
 }

public myForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Dictionary<string, string> Departments = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Departments = GetDepartments(string.Empty, out bool _isOff);

    dtDepartments = new DataTable();
    dtDepartments.TableName = "DEPARTMENTS";
    DataColumn idColumn = dtDepartments.Columns.Add("NUM", typeof(string));
    dtDepartments.Columns.Add("NAME", typeof(string));
    dtDepartments.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { idColumn };

    foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> kvP in Departments)
    {
        dtDepartments.Rows.Add(new object[] { kvP.Key, kvP.Value });
    }
}
```

and this is how I populate the list in the event method

```
private void txtFilter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filter = "NAME LIKE '%" + txtFilter.Text + "%'";
    DataRow[] foundRows = dtDepartments.Select(filter);

    if (foundRows.Length > 0)
    {
        lvDepartments.Visible = true;
        ResizeListView(foundRows.Length);
        PopulateListView(foundRows);
    }
}

void ResizeListView(int _rows)
{
    lvDepartments.Height = Math.Min(25 + (20 * _rows), 205);
}

void PopulateListView(DataRow[] _foundRows)
{
    lvDepartments.Items.Clear();
    ListViewItem depNum = new ListViewItem("NUM", 0);
    ListViewItem depName = new ListViewItem("NAME", 0);
    foreach (DataRow row in _foundRows)
    {
        depNum.SubItems.Add(row.Field<string>("NUM"));
        depName.SubItems.Add(row.Field<string>("NAME"));
    }

    lvDepartments.Columns.Add("Number", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    lvDepartments.Columns.Add("Name", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

    lvDepartments.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { depNum, depName });
}
```

The `DataRow[]` array is correctly populated, the `ResizeListView(int _rows)` method does its job in adapting the list height, the `ListView` correctly shows the columns header, but the rest is just blank rows.

I've followed [these instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN, but I can't really find what I'm missing.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Thanks-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're adding one ListViewItem per column and one SubItem per row. It goes the other way around.

The first column is populated from the ListViewItem [Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.text(v=vs.110).aspx) property. The second thru nth columns are populated from the strings supplied to `SubItems.Add()`.

The above assumes you are using the details [View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.view(v=vs.110).aspx) mode, which is the only view that allows multiple columns.

```
void PopulateListView(DataRow[] _foundRows)
{
    lvDepartments.Items.Clear();
    foreach (var row in _foundRows)
    {
        var item = new ListViewItem { Text = row.Field<String>("NUM") };
        item.SubItems.Add( row.Field<String>("NAM") );
        lvDepartments.Items.Add( item );
    }
}
```

Or if you're LINQ-y

```
void PopulateListView(DataRow[] _foundRows)
{
    lvDepartments.Items.Clear();
    lvDepartments.Items.AddRange
    (
        _foundRows.Cast<DataRow>().Select
        ( 
            row =>
            {
                var item = new ListViewItem
                {
                    Text = row.Field<string>("NUM")
                };
                item.SubItems.Add( row.Field<string>("NAME") );
                return item;
            }
        )
        .ToArray()
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much... I got the other way around :)